# Setting the first counter in amsthm

Tags: numbering, counters, amsthm

I am editing my lecture notes and use the amsthm package. As I missed some of the lectures, I would like to set the counter of the first theorem on the page to some number. Only the first one, e.g. 12.7. Other should follow that numbering. How could one set the counter in this way?
It has just worked with \setcounter{section}{12} and \setcounter{defi}{7}.
but, I have a different numbering for other theorem styles, as defi refers to the definition style and anme to remark. Any way to set all the counters at once to get a consecutive numbering?

```
\documentclass[12pt,ansinew]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{anme}{Anmerkung}[section]
% many other newtheorems here
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]
% many other newtheorems here
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{11}
\section{Section A}
\setcounter{defi}{6}
\defi \blindtext
\anme \blindtext
\section{Section B}
\defi \blindtext
\anme \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [complete, minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that shows all the counters (environments; their names and definitions) you're working with you want to synchronize. It would help future visitors, but also the community in trying to recreate your exact setup. Answers come faster that way.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand your question: what’s wrong with `\setcounter{section}{11} \setcounter{defi}{6}` (followed by, say, `\setcounter{anme}{3}`)?

Comment: Using `\defi` and `\anme` is wrong to begin with. You *must* use `\begin{defi}<text>\end{defi}` and similarly for the other theorem-like structures.

Comment: also the syntax `\defi` is wrong you have no end to the theorem settings, always use `\begin{defi}...`\end{defi}`

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti if I set nothing manually, there is a consequtive numbering for all theorems. If I set something manually, remark and definition style theorems are counted separatly. As I wrote, I have many "newtheorems" in one style, and it is almost impossible to change all the counters manually. Still, they become not consequtive.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had been using the right syntax the whole time, but once I saw that putting just \defi makes the same result (at least, I cannot see any difference).

Comment: @Kirill: But you *want* definitions and theorems to be numbered in separate sequences, don’t you?

Comment: @Kirill No, the output is definitely not the same. Trust me.

Comment: your entire document is inside multiple nested theorems as you never end the scope, it's completely wrong!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti no, I have written that the numbering should be consecutive.

Comment: @Kirill: You should say `\newtheorem{defi}[anme]{Definition}`, then (or something like that).  **Edit:** I didn’t even notice your incorrect syntax using `\defi` etc. instead of `\begin{defi} ... \end{defi}` etc.; I guess you should better have a look to the manuals! (;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti You are right. As I said above, I used the correct one all the time, but I have seen no difference as I used the wrong one. Now, David Carlisle inspires me to use the correct one again, and I do it. I have thousands of pages of manuals, and use them like treat to target principle, as I cannot read them all through.

Comment: Btw, @GustavoMezzetti sorry, I have overseen the essential part of your feedback! I have fixed it, it works! :) Thank you!

Comment: @Kirill: Well, `masthdoc.pdf` is only 15 page long, and you can leave out the “advanced features” and stop reading at page 8.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I will not argue. Geomerty, array, graphicx, hyperref and other 30 I use together with the LaTeX companion have more than 15 pages and I cannot say that they are less important. But, you are right. It is only 8 pages, and they are worht of reading them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll recapitulate the comments that have been made in an answer, so thar this question can be closed.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath} % strictly speaking, this is not needed, but...
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{theorem} % it's the default, but added for clarity
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[theo]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{coro}[theo]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}[theo]{Definition}



\begin{document}

\section{First section}

Some text at the beginning of the section.
This is actually the first section in my paper.
\begin{defi}
    Define something.
\end{defi}
A preliminary result:
\begin{prop}
    Blah blah blah.
\end{prop}
Another result:
\begin{prop}
    Mumble mumble.
\end{prop}
My first theorem:
\begin{theo}
    State something.
\end{theo}
With a corollary:
\begin{coro}
    It follows immediately.
\end{coro}
That's enough for the first section.

\setcounter{section}{11}

\section{Later section}

\setcounter{theo}{6} % MUST follow the "\section" command

Some text at the beginning of the section.
This should actually be the twelfth section in my paper.
\begin{defi}
    Define something else.
\end{defi}
Another preliminary result:
\begin{prop}
    Whatever you want.
\end{prop}
Another theorem:
\begin{theo}
    State something.
\end{theo}
With a corollary:
\begin{coro}
    It follows immediately.
\end{coro}
And so on.

\end{document}
```